# Load Json Data Directly in sqlite Manager

Tags: ios, iphone, json, sqlite

I am getting data from the server for my application, now I want to store that data (server data) into sqlite database for offline work. so I can do work while internet is not available.
Please tell me how to store JSON Data response to sqlite database or is it possible to to import data file to upload bunch of data to sqlite file ?

It's very important for me so guys please let me know how to do this ? Please reply asap so I can solve issue asap, I am new as ios developer so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First parse json gety arecords in array. and then directly save in your sqlite database.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks the minimal understanding.

Comment: @LaszloPapp : I hope now you get my point ? if you have any issue let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is way

[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6355244/2439156)

You have first gate json data into an array an after that you save that array into sqlite DB using passing value from your JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is not possible to import JSON data into sqlite manager. But there is a chance your key of JSON data and the sqlite column is same then its possible with help of Sqlite wrapper like FMDB